# Spree 3.0 emails are not being sent (delivered)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, spree

I've got Spree 3.0, rails 4.2.1, nginx, unicorn. Here is spree-related gem list

```
gem 'spree', github:'spree/spree', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree/spree_static_content', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem "spree_product_zoom", git: "git://github.com/spree/spree_product_zoom.git", branch: '3-0-stable'
```

Trying to set up ActionMailer via config/environments/production.rb with YandexMail or GoogleMail. Here's about Yandex.Mail

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.yandex.ru",
port: 465,
domain: 'mydomain',
user_name: 'myemail',
password: 'mypass',
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true }
```

And emails are not sent (during checkout/sending email order again). There are no error logs in production, however it's the "*upstream timed out*" error. And increasing proxy timeout didn't help.
In my production logs it shows that's Ok

```
D, [2015-05-17T18:52:50.964229 #4836] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [54f73692-30bc-4354-9a6f-bb29fe6d54e2]
Spree::OrderMailer#confirm_email: processed outbound mail in 1908.9ms
```

Tried to use mailcatcher with spree_mail_settings and mailcatcher with Action Mailer set up - doesn't work. Mailcatcher doesn't show any emails no matter mails are sent (both via spree admin when I press resend email or checkot and via console script).

But anyway, no matter what I do (change, fix) emails are not sent! Don't know what to do else, guys. **Please, help me!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue bymyself. Got to turn on stl, ttl

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.yandex.ru",
port: 465,
domain: 'mydomain',
user_name: 'myemail',
password: 'mypass',
authentication: :login,
ssl: true,
enable_starttls_auto: true,
tls: true }
```

I guess tutorials I saw before are old version Rails and there were no tls support in the box.